# Changing Code At Runtime While Debugging

Tags: eclipse, perl, debugging, compilation, epic

I am using **Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2 , EPIC 0.5.46** and Strawberry Perl 5 version 18 for perl programming. For debugging I am using **Eclipse debugger and PadWalker** .

I have an interactive perl program that writes to files based on answers provided by the users to multiple prompts. While debugging , every time i change a single line of code I have to rerun the whole program again and provide inputs to every prompt , which is really time consuming.

**Is there a way to make changes to the code in a sub routine , in the middle of debugging session such that the instruction pointer resets itself to the first line of that sub routine.** This way i do not have to restart the session to recompile the new code.

Appreciate your inputs and suggestions. Thank You!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do can be done, and I've done it many times in Perl myself. For example, see [this](https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Trepan::CmdProcessor::Command::Load::Command).

However although what you describe may work (and is a bit dangerous), the way it is generally done a bit different and safer.

First one has to assume a regular kind of command structure like a command processor, or say a web server.

In a command processor or web server, you read a command (or get a web request), perform an action, then read another command, perform another action and so on. From your description, it sounds like you have such a structure.

In my case, I have each debugger command stored as in Perl file. This is helpful not only for facilitating this task, but also for understanding, testing and changing the code.

Given this kind of program structure, instead of trying to change the program counter, you complete the command and at the level where you are about to read a new command, you make the change and then reload the file which changes the code.

The specific Perl construct to do this is called *do*. Don't use *require* or *use* which will load in a Perl file only if that file or module hasn't  been previously loaded. In your situation, you want to reload even if it has been loaded before.

So now how do you get to be able to issue a *do* command? As you suggest, you could do it through a debugger. Assuming you have this overall program stucture as described above, you put the breakpoint somewhere a common point in the caller which loops over things to process, rather than try to change things in indvidual commands.

And you don't even need a debugger to do this! Many web frameworks like Ruby on Rails, have a "development" mode where they save timestamps on files that implement functionality. If the file has changed they issue the "do" command before running the request.